# cuDNN on Google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

When I run following line:

```
import tensorflow
```

I'm getting error like:

> Importerror : libcudnn. so. 6 : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I'm using Google Colab for my project. I'm using `tensorflow-gpu 1.4`. Somehow I managed to install `Cuda 8.0` on Google Colab. But I need to install `cuDNN`, which is necessary requirement of `tensorflow-gpu 1.4`. I should not upgrade tensorflow version to 1.12.

How to install cuDNN on Google Colab?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the various packages' versions correct for using a GPU is complicated, which is why Colab does it for you. You're going to have a bad time if you try to use another set of versions, but if you really want to try then the answer is to follow NVIDIA's documentation for how to install their stuff.

Note that there's a definite cutoff for how far back you go because userland libs and driver versions are not independent, and you will not be able to change the driver version on colab no matter what you do.

Comment: I can't find cudnn on colab. I already looked at /usr/local/cuda/

Comment: Does `!dpkg -L libcudnn8-dev` help?

Comment: Wow, extremely helpful command. Everyone should learn about `dpkg` this. Thanks.